# How to use Visual Basic, Mindstorms NXT and USB communication Altogether?

Tags: usb, basic, nxt, lego-mindstorms

I have been researching for a couple of days, and i have not found anything I understand about sending direct commands to the NXT via USB. All of the tutorials I have found are based on Bluetooth communication, and the information I have found about USB is always like "Better change to bluetooth", or "Think about it as a COM port"

I had previously sent those commands via Bluetooth, but the connection fails too often to be useful, and is slower than USB.

USB connection is not detected as a COM port, but I know it is posible to control motors and get sensor input with a USB connection, because the LEGO software does so. It has that remote control feature that allows user to activate motors from the PC, and can read sensor input as well.

So, my question is, How can I send and recieve those direct commands via USB? and, Is there any way to do so in Visual Basic 2008?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MonoBrick Communication Library to do this. See http://www.monobrick.dk/software/monobrick/.

Alternately, you could use the Fantom driver from the official LEGO Software developer kit. http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/software/nxt-sdk/